# need regex to get string before and after sepearted by a colon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having strings like following in javascript

```
lolo dolo:279bc880-25c6-11e3-bc22-3c970e02b4ec
```

i want to extract the string before : and after it and store them in a variable. I am not a regex expert so i am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No regex needed, use [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var x = 'lolo dolo:279bc880-25c6-11e3-bc22-3c970e02b4ec'.split(':');
var before = x[0]
var after = x[1]
```

Comment: If someone see, they think that we sit in the same room :)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `split()`,No need of regex.

Delimit your string with `:`,So it makes your string in to two parts.

```
var splitter  ="lolo dolo:279bc880-25c6-11e3-bc22-3c970e02b4ec".split(':');


var first  =splitter[0];
var second =splitter[1];
```